# How to set the Spark streaming receiver frequency?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

My requirement is to process the hourly data of a stock market.
i.e, get the data from source once per streaming interval and process it via DStream.

I have implemented a custom receiver to scrap/monitor the website by implementing onStart() and onStop() methods and its working.

Challenges encountered:

- Receiver thread is fetching the data continuously i.e, multiples times per interval.
- Unable to coordinate receiver and DStream execution time interval.

Options I tried:

1. Receiver Thread to sleep for few seconds (equal to streaming interval).
   In this case data is not the latest data while processing.

[image]

[image]

```
class CustomReceiver(interval: Int)
    extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) {

  def onStart() {
    new Thread("Website Scrapper") {
      override def run() { receive() }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {

  }

  /** Create a socket connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
  private def receive() {
    println("Entering receive:" + new Date());
    try {
      while (!isStopped) {
        val scriptsLTP = StockMarket.getLiveStockData()
        for ((script, ltp) <- scriptsLTP) {
          store(script + "," + ltp)
        }
        println("sent data")
        System.out.println("going to sleep:" + new Date());
        Thread.sleep(3600 * 1000);
        System.out.println("awaken from sleep:" + new Date());
      }
      println("Stopped receiving")
      restart("Trying to connect again")
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>
        restart("Error receiving data", t)
    }
    println("Exiting receive:" + new Date());
  }
}
```

How to make the Spark Streaming receiver in sync with DStream processing?

Comment: Would getting the data when the streaming interval starts be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case doesn't seem a good fit for Spark Streaming. The interval is long enough to consider this as a regular batch job instead. That way, we can make better use of the cluster resources.

I would rewrite it as a Spark Job by parallelizing the target tickers, using a `mapPartitions` to use the executors as distributed web scrappers and then process as intended.

Then schedule the Spark job to run each hour with `cron` or more advanced alternatives, such as Chronos at the exact times wanted.

Comment: as per your view, what is the maximum feasible interval for a streaming job?

Comment: @VijayInnamuri that depends on the usecase, so I'm not going to dear to put a number.  If the data you had to process was coming constantly, but you only needed 1 report/hr, I'd consider Spark Streaming. The point here is that Spark Streaming is about **streaming** data and your usecase resembles more a batch job that needs to run at specific times. Also notice that Spark Streaming will allocate cluster resources  for the time it runs. Your usecase looks like few minutes of processing every hour. It would detrimental to constantly block a good chunk of resource  for such low usage,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.